# How to to access /sys/bus/usb/devices/ from qemu with AppArmor enabled? ("Cannot Open File" and "Cannot read serial from...")

Tags: usb, virtual-machine, qemu, apparmor

I'm trying to access an USB device with AQEMU. For this I have added an USB port in the media options. But when starting the virtual machine I'm getting these errors:

> AQEMU Warning [..] >>>
>   Sender: bool System_Info::Scan_USB_Sys( QList &list )
>   Message: Cannot read serial from /sys/bus/usb/devices/
>
> AQEMU Warning [..] >>>
>   Sender: bool System_Info::Read_SysFS_File(
>   const QString &path, QString &data )
>   Message: Cannot Open File "/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-6/serial"!

The AppArmor profile for aqemu already had:

> /sys/bus/ r,
>   /sys/bus/** r,

and after adding these:

> /sys/bus/usb/devices/** r,
>   /sys/bus/usb/devices/ r,

and running `sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor restart` I'm still getting the same errors.

How to enable qemu to access the USB device and prevent these errors?